# What is the usage of $& in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I was looking into special parameters in bash. I am curious to know what is `$&` and how it is different from `$_`.

I see the following output when running the commands but could not locate the meaning as well.

```
k@Linux:~$ echo $&
[1] 12397
$
k@Linux:~$ echo $n

[1]+  Done                    echo $
k@Linux:~$
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$&` is not a single token/special variable, it is simply `$` and `&`.

The command `echo $&` is treated as `echo $ &`, which echos a literal `$` in the background.

`$_` on the other hand is a special variable that expands to the last argument of the most recent command executed.

Answer (score 5):

While the `bash` aspect has been covered, your question makes me think you've come across those variables in `perl` code.

`$&` and `$_` are special variables in `perl`. And they are especially found in `perl` code called from the shell code.

`$_` is the default variable many `perl` functions and operators work on. That variable is also the default variable set by input operators.

In:

```
perl -pe 'some-code' < some-input
```

Some-code is run for every line of some-input, with the line stored in `$_`, and the content of the `$_` is printed after some-code has run.

The `s/regex/replacement/` operator works on `$_` by default. So you often find things like:

```
perl -pe 's/foo/bar/'
```

Which is short for:

```
perl -pe '$_ =~ s/foo/bar/'
```

(above, `$_`, as far as the *shell* is concerned is just part of a verbatim argument passed to the `perl` interpreter, it is not a shell variable. That verbatim argument is passed as `perl` expression (`-e`) to `perl`, and it's for `perl` that it is interpreted as a variable).

`$&` is another special `perl` variable that expands to whatever was matched by the last matching operator (`m/.../` , `s/.../.../`...).

For instance:

```
$ echo foo | perl -lne '
    print "The last character in $_ is $&" if m/.$/'
The last character in foo is o
```

Or:

```
$ echo foo bar | perl -pe 's/[aeiou]+/<$&>/g'
f<oo> b<a>r
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing `&` means you are going to run a particular command in the backend or as a job. So that is what the output of `echo $&` gives.